# 500 internal error trying get a response from test

Tags: .net, api, integration-testing

I am keep getting 500 error trying to make any calls from my test project. I am following microsoft guide https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/test/integration-tests?view=aspnetcore-6.0. Now I am using sqlite for dev part, later I'll switch to sqlite.
Test case:

```
public class CategoryContollerTests
{
    private readonly WebApplicationFactory<Program> _factory;
    public CategoryContollerTests(WebApplicationFactory<Program> factory)
    {
        _factory = factory;
    }
    [Fact]
    public async Task Get_ReturnCategory()
    {
        var client = _factory.CreateClient();

        var response = await client.GetAsync("api/Categories");
        int i = 0;
    }
}
```

Main project Program file:

```
    var myAllowSpecificOrigins = "_myAllowSpecificOrigins";

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
.ReadFrom.Configuration(builder.Configuration)
.Enrich.FromLogContext()
.CreateLogger();

builder.Logging.ClearProviders();
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(logger);

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddControllers();
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerDoc("v1", new OpenApiInfo() { Title = "Test API", Version = "v1" });
});

builder.Services.AddAutoMapper(AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies());
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DataContext>(opt =>
{
    opt.UseSqlite(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection"));
});


//Enable CORS
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy(name: myAllowSpecificOrigins,
    builder =>
    {
        builder.WithOrigins("http://localhost:4200")
        .AllowAnyMethod()
        .AllowAnyHeader();
    });
});



var app = builder.Build();


// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
    {
        c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "Test API v1");
    });
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.MapControllers();

app.Run();

public partial class Program { }
```

What could cause the problem? (App works fine)
Read the logs, and occured that the problem is with the database

> [2022-12-24 15:52:22.034 +01:00  ERR]  An unhandled exception has occurred while executing the request.
> Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException (0x80004005): SQLite Error 1: 'no such table: Categories'.
> at Microsoft.Data.Sqlite.SqliteException.ThrowExceptionForRC(Int32 rc, sqlite3 db)
> Still don't know how to fix this, it should simply use my database which works fine.

Comment: Probably an exception that is thrown during the call - did you check the logs? Adding them to your post would be helpful

Comment: @Nannanas You were right, I found the exception, coude you help me further to fix it, if you can ofc.

Comment: Looks like you did not apply all migrations to the database or your test is using a different database than you think (maybe because the test uses a different configuration file and therefore a different connection string).